# sort elements in an array by specific given value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I'm receiving an array of objects like this (there are many fields i'm showing only the few):

```
dataset = [
{branchID : "IN123", customerID : "CB1234", customerName : "Alex", amountApplied : "1000.0"},
{branchID : "IN124", customerID : "CB1235", customerName : "Tom", amountApplied : "2000.0"},
{branchID : "IN128", customerID : "CB1236", customerName : "Adrian", amountApplied : "5000.0"}
]
```

I need to see the order of fields in this order

```
dataset = [
{branchID : "IN123", amountApplied : "1000.0", customerName : "Alex", customerID : "CB1234"}
{branchID : "IN124", amountApplied : "2000.0", customerName : "Tom" , customerID : "CB1235"}
{branchID : "IN128", amountApplied : "5000.0", customerName : "Adrian", customerID : "CB1236" }
]
```

i tried this :

```
    var ordering = {},
          sortOrder = ['branchID',,'amountApplied','customerName','customerID']
         for (var i=0; i<sortOrder.length; i++)
         ordering[sortOrder[i]] = i;

            response.dataSet.sort( function(a, b) {
             return (ordering[a] - ordering[b]) || a.localeCompare(b);
         });
```

it shows .localCompare is not an function.
any advice how to achvive this

Comment: Do you want to sort the elements (objects) in the array or do you want to sort the **properties** in each object?

Comment: I need to sort the elements in the array, please share your thoughts

Comment: And the duplicate link doesn't answer my question, it says how to sort by alphabetically, but I want to sort by the custom order as  i mentioned, I don't know why it is closed here.

Comment: It seems to me that you want to change the property order in the objects, not sort the elements in the array. The order of the elements in the desired array **is the same**.

Comment: yes you are right, can you provide help on this

Comment: There is a deleted answer that answers your exact problem, I just voted to undelete it.